# Trying to find duplicates in a Struct Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates

I've attempted to find if the user has inputted a product id value that's a duplicate and if so, it just tells them that it's a duplicate value and then returns to the menu in my switch statement.

The actual result i get, is that after "productsfilled == 0", it won't utilise the For Loops to check for the duplicates and productsfilled will remain at 1. I've looked online and this way of finding duplicates tends to work and i have used it previously in my code, so I don't think that could be the issue.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
int productsfilled;

struct ProductData{
    int product_id;
    char product_name[120];
    int price;
};

int quiz_5(){
    char ch;
    int size, input = 0;

    struct ProductData products[20];

    while(1){

        printf("\nWelcome To The Super Mall's Product List. Please Select An Option:\n1. Add Product\n2. Display Product\n3. Delete Product\n");

        fflush(stdin);

        switch(getchar()){

            case '1':


                printf("\nPlease Enter Product ID:");
                scanf("%d",&products[productsfilled].product_id);

                printf("\nPlease Enter Product Name:");
                scanf("%s",&products[productsfilled].product_name);

                printf("\nPlease Enter Product Price:");
                scanf("%d",&products[productsfilled].price);

                printf("Productsfilled: %d",productsfilled);

                if(productsfilled == 0){
                    productsfilled = 1;
                    break;
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < productsfilled;i++){
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < productsfilled;j++){
                            if(products[i].product_id == products[j].product_id){
                                printf("\nPlease Use Different Product ID");
                                break;
                            }else{
                                printf("test");
                                productsfilled += 1;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }

                break;

            case '2':
                while(1){
                    for(int i = 0;i < productsfilled;i++){
                        printf("Product ID: %d      Product Name: %s    Product Price: %d\n",products[i].product_id,products[i].product_name,products[i].price);
                    }
                        printf("Please Press Enter To Continue");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        if(getchar() == '\n'){
                            break;
                        }
                    }


            case '3':
                break;

            case '\n':
                break;

            default:
                printf("Please Select An Option:\n1. Add Product\n2. Display Product\n3. Delete Product: ");
        }
    }
}




int main() {
    int input = 1;
    printf("Welcome to my assignment. Which quiz do you want to run (please input the number of the quiz e.g. for quiz 1, type 1): \n-Quiz 1\n-Quiz 2\n-Quiz 3\n-Quiz 4\n-Quiz 5\n-Quiz 6\n-Quiz 7\n");
    while(input == 1){
        fflush(stdin);
        switch(getchar()){
             case '5':
                quiz_5();
                break;
            case '\n':
                printf("Welcome to my assignment. Which quiz do you want to run (please input the number of the quiz e.g. for quiz 1, type 1): \n-Quiz 1\n-Quiz 2\n-Quiz 3\n-Quiz 4\n-Quiz 5\n-Quiz 6\n-Quiz 7\n");
                getchar();
            default:
                printf("Invalid Input\n");

    } }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't increment `productsfilled` before you enter the loop...therefore, `productsfilled` is always 1 less than the actual length of your array which means that you don't compare all elements in the array.

Try your program on 2 inputs, both with the same ID. You'll see that you don't compare anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong when using scanf for string input:

```
scanf("%s",&products[productsfilled].product_name);
```

You should not use `&`, you should use as below:

```
scanf("%119s",products[productsfilled].product_name);
```

OT, in main function:

```
switch(getchar()){
             case '5':
...
```

Because `getchar()` will return `int` value, so if you want to  access to quiz_5, you have to type `35` (`ANSCI` code) instead of type `5` when you run your program.

```
char a = '5';
```

similar to:

```
int a = 35;
```